# building Debian package fails after even a minor change to code

Tags: packaging, deb

I am able to build Debian package `make` using following procedure:

```
apt-get source make
cd make-*
dpkg-buildpackage --build=binary --no-sign
```

But as soon as I make any change to the code, even [changing one character in a string](https://paste.ofcode.org/TJ6XZiPPvQxX7M9KyadmQi), then the build fails during the tests:

```
1 Test in 1 Category Failed (See .diff* files in work dir for details) :-(

make[4]: *** [Makefile:1373: check-regression] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory '/mnt/src/deb/MAKE/make-dfsg-4.2.1/debian/build-make-guile'
make[3]: *** [Makefile:1114: check-am] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory '/mnt/src/deb/MAKE/make-dfsg-4.2.1/debian/build-make-guile'
make[2]: *** [Makefile:820: check-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/mnt/src/deb/MAKE/make-dfsg-4.2.1/debian/build-make-guile'
dh_auto_test: error: cd debian/build-make-guile && make -j8 check VERBOSE=1 returned exit code 2
make[1]: *** [debian/rules:50: override_dh_auto_test] Error 255
make[1]: Leaving directory '/mnt/src/deb/MAKE/make-dfsg-4.2.1'
make: *** [debian/rules:24: build] Error 2
dpkg-buildpackage: error: debian/rules build subprocess returned exit status 2
```

I have pasted the full output [here](https://paste.ofcode.org/35LBCkutf2fqASTR6rK3LVg)

How can I build the package with custom changes ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ideally, you’d update the test suite to take your changes into account.

It is however possible to avoid the test suite altogether, using [a standardized build option](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-source.html#debian-rules-and-deb-build-options):

```
DEB_BUILD_OPTIONS=nocheck dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc
```

Comment: thank you. How do I combine more  build options? This does not seem to work: `export DEB_BUILD_OPTIONS=noautodbgsym,nocheck`

Comment: It’s explained in the first paragraph of the section of Policy that I linked to.

Comment: @400theCat multiple options in `DEB_BUILD_OPTIONS` in must be separated by whitespace.